# Do resistances stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance, stacking

If a creature had resistance to spells, and then cast fire resistance on it, would it take only 1/4 damage from all fire spells?

Comment: [Related] [Do a Barbarian's different damage resistances stack or just overlap?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63769/do-a-barbarians-different-damage-resistances-stack-or-just-overlap)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Nope, they don't stack.

Per the rules on [damage resistance and vulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageResistanceandVulnerability) (PHB, p. 197):

> Multiple instances of resistance or vulnerability that affect the same damage type count as only one instance. For example, if a creature has resistance to fire damage as well as resistance to all nonmagical damage, the damage of nonmagical fire is reduced by half against the creature, not reduced by three-quarters.